# How I can CONCAT vertical lines from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

If have following problem. I cannot get values from MySQL when I have them separated with `|`

I have following string:

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE CONCAT(',', category, ',') REGEXP ',(lc_8|swimming),'`

and this string only works when in my MySQL I have column `category` with value `lc_8,swimming,`

How I can change string above to get same values but if in column I have `lc_8|swimming|`?

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a special character in regexps. You would need to escape it, like `\|`. Try:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE CONCAT(',', category, ',') REGEXP ',(lc_8\|swimming),'
```

Characters that need escaping in regexes are as follows:

```
* ? + [ ( ) { } ^ $ | \
```

If you really want to match the parentheses in your example, you would need to quote them as well.

Answer (score 0):

`(` and `|` have a special meaning in a regular expression, you need to escape them.

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE CONCAT(',', REPLACE(category, '|', '\\|'), ',') REGEXP ',\(lc_8\|swimming\),'
```

But if you're searching a comma-delimited list, it would be better to use the function designed for that:

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('(lc_8|swimming)', category)
```

Even better would be to *not* store comma-delimited lists in the first place, but put the categories in a separate table with one row for each category.